# Ruby variable assigned to just the keyword "new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a hard one to search for, but I've got a line of Ruby in a class method where a variable is first declared by assigning it a bare `new` keyword and I'm not exactly sure what's going on here:

```
  def self.html_render_controller(post)
    controller = new
    controller.action = 'show'
    controller.post = post
    controller.render_to_string
  end
```

Coming from other languages, it looks to me like `controller` is implicitly being initialized as an object of some kind. And `render_to_string` is a Rails built-in, so my best guess is `controller` is initialized as some kind of Rails object?

I guess my question is really what is the value of `controller` after that first assignment? Or what kind of execution rules or even just documentation in Ruby would point me in the right direction for understanding this kind of shorthand?

Comment: "Or what kind of execution rules or even just documentation in Ruby would point me in the right direction for understanding this kind of shorthand?" – It is called a "method call" (more precisely "message send") and should be covered in almost any Ruby tutorial near the very beginning. It is *the* fundamental way in which "things get done" in Ruby.

Comment: that's kind of what i mean about being hard to google. "ruby message send tutorial" brings back a lot of SMS and MMS docs, but not a lot of useful information on implicitly instantiating a class from within itself using a shorthand call

Comment: You won't find a tutorial on message sends in Ruby. *Any* Ruby tutorial will cover them at the *very beginning*, since it is *impossible* to anything in Ruby without message sends. Almost everything is a message send in Ruby. There are 4 message sends in the code you posted, and the one in the first line is in no way special or different from the other three.

Comment: i'd disagree. a bare `new` doesn't say what it does explicitly. which is why i asked the question in the first place, there's some implicit ruby knowledge here that's hard to search for, but is relatively easy for any decent human being to explain once they see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not exactly sure what's going on here

It's the `new` method of your class, i.e. it returns a new instance of the class your `html_render_controller` method is defined in.

Since you come from other languages, it might be easier to think of `controller = new()` (which in fact works just fine in Ruby, but it's more idiomatic to omit empty parentheses unless needed)

> what kind of execution rules or even just documentation in Ruby would point me in the right direction for understanding this kind of shorthand?

This is Ruby's default method calling mechanism when omitting a [receiver](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver): *"`self` is the default receiver. If you don't specify any receiver `self` will be used."*

In instance methods, `self` refers to the current instance. In class methods, `self` refers to the class the method is defined in.

These three code snippets are all equivalent: <sup>*</sup>

```
class MyController
  def self.foo
    controller = new
  end
end

class MyController
  def self.foo
    controller = self.new
  end
end

class MyController
  def self.foo
    controller = MyController.new
  end
end
```

You could also replace the `self` after `def` with the class name:

```
class MyController
  def MyController.foo
    controller = MyController.new
  end
end
```

And using the latter, most explicit form, the method could even be defined *outside* the class body:

```
class MyController
end

def MyController.foo
  controller = MyController.new
end
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that the above examples are not *identical*. For example, with sub-classes, `self.new` would dynamically create an instance of the respective (sub-)class whereas `MyController.new` would always create an instance of `MyController`. And you usually want to define your methods within the class body to ensure proper constant lookup.

Comment: `controller = new()`, oof, yeah that was kind of my concern looking at it at first. an implicit constructor, but no clear, explicit semantics in the source code itself on what was being constructed. super useful on the examples, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is not so weird as ruby code. It Is quite straight forward.

`new` is not a keyword is a method called on the implicit `self`.
You do not need parenthesis to call a method in Ruby.

If you call a method without an explicit receiver in Ruby,  the receiver is going to be `self`, inside the body of the method `self.html_render_controller`, `self` references the class where the method is defined.

So executing `new` inside the method `self.html_render_controller` just return a new object of the class where the method is defined.

You can have more details on `new` from the [documentation on](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Class.html#method-c-new) `Class`, that is the class of any class in Ruby, being a class just an object of the class `Class`.

Comment: "You do not need parenthesis to call a method in Ruby.", right i always forget that bit. also, super helpful to now know that `new` can implicitly be `self`, that definitely helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`new` is instantiating an object of the class where this `html_render_controller` method is.

You can change it to `self.new` instead of `new`, then it's clearer where this method is coming from. Since `html_render_controller` is a class method, `self` will be the class where the method is.

```
class Foobar
  def self.foo
    foobar = new
    # `foobar` is a new instance of Foobar
  end
end
```